# Salesforce Identity - App Launcher

Tags: identity

On the [splash screen for Salesforce Identity](http://www.salesforce.com/platform/identity/), there's a screenshot of a nifty app launcher page:

[image]

I realize that Salesforce Identity hasn't formally launched yet, but almost all of the pieces are already GA (SAML, OAuth, Remote Access, Connected Apps, IDP over SAML, etc.).

- Is this page already available in some way?
- If not, is SF identity available through a pilot program?
- Have you heard any shareable information (safe harbor, of course), about when this feature may be released?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is included in the Winter '14 release.

Answer (score 6):

In Summer '13 ([safe harbor](http://www.salesforce.com/company/investor/safe-harbor.jsp)!) you will be able to build that page by simply enumerating [AppMenuItem](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_referencepre/Content/sforce_api_objects_appmenuitem.htm) records from Visualforce.