# App Launcher not available in Menu

Tags: app

Somehow, I am not able to see App Launcher Menu and it supposed to be available after Winter 14.

I have gone through this Video - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_cTGhxPJHQ and also from this post [Salesforce Identity - App Launcher](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11687/salesforce-identity-app-launcher), However i am not able to configure it.

"Use Identity Feature" i also provided in profile.

As, option was not available so i tried to install "Salesforce clients connected apps" also but didnt worked.

Comment: I have the same situation.  But for an added twist, all the identity stuff if available in my sandboxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is answer to my own Question.

Permission "Enable Salesforce Identity", needs to be enabled by Salesforce Support. My Organization was not having this permission.

Now, its Working.